# Can't replace specific letters with another one correctly

Tags: java, replace

I have a String, and i'd like to repalce specific letters with another one, I have a json response that contain which letter to replaced with which letter .

For example, my String is 'abh f'
And Json from and to will be - a => bf , b => 423_ , h => 2Re , f => ab

Here's the issue, when replaceing, it will first replace a to bf, and then it will replace the b in abh and the b in converted a (bf), and that will corrupt the whole idea, i couldn't come with a good idea, i've tried looping throw each letter from the string but i wasn't able to loop throw the json without getting OutOfMemory .

Any Ideas? here's the code

```
  for (int i = 0; i < m_jArry.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jo_inside = m_jArry.getJSONObject(i);

                    String Original = jo_inside.getString("from");
                    String To = jo_inside.getString("to");

                        NewText = NewText.replace(" ","$");
                        NewText = NewText.replace(Original ,To);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first replace each input string with a token, like `{i}` where i is the index of the input, and afterwards replace every token with the output string of the corresponding index.

You just have to make sure that the token is not contained in the original string nor the inputs/outputs.

That's, however, easier but very inefficient. The best way would be to iterate over the string with a for per char, and perform the replace by hand, that is, something like this:

```
String input = /* param of your method */;

Map<Character, String> replacements = new HashMap<>();
// Fill map in, like replacements.put('a', "bf");
// Parsing the json every time could be time consuming.
// The best structure here is a HashMap.
// So I'd suggest that you first create it from the json and then use it whenever.

String output = "";

for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
    if (map.containsKey(c)) {
        output += map.get(c);
    } else {
        output += c;
    }
}

return output; // the result is here
```

Comment: The thing is, I want to loop in the String letter by letter, and check if the letter is there in ListArray, if YES, get the letter from the second ListArray to change it, how that would be possible ? as i understand what i need to do, but the code always fails me .

Comment: @AboHani, I've improved my answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on how many times you want the replacement action happens.

If only one time, it's easy.You can split the original string and do replacement action for each char and merge the result finally.

But if you allow the replacement action for every token in the json happens more than one times, I think there is no way to resovle the problem without OOM when you get a json like this:

> {a=>b ,b=>a}

Answer (score 0):

This is the first time to answer the question,i hope the answer is useful to you.I think we can replace the letter one by one,but not change the initial input.Here is my code.

```
String input = "abhf";
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
for(int i = 0;i < input.length();i++)
{
    char value = input.charAt(i);
    switch(value)
    {
        case 'a':
            result.append("bf");
            break;
        case 'b':
            result.append("423");
            break;
        case 'h':
            result.append("2Re");
            break;
        case 'f':
            result.append("ab");
            break;
        default:
            result.append(value);
            break;
    }
}

System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Comment: You missed a point, i don't know what i need to change, because the user select "What letter to change" and "To which letter it should be changed to ", as he may not add "a" letter at all, but may add " i ", or a letter in his own language. That's how i'm getting the Json response, the user make it, not me .