# Multiple string replacements without affecting substituted text in subsequent iterations

Tags: java

I've posted about letters earlier, but this is an another topic, I have a json response that contain 2 objects, `from` and `to` , `from` is what to change, and `to` is what it will be changed to .

My code is :

```
// for example, the EnteredText is "ab b test a b" .
EnteredString = EnteredText.getText().toString();
for (int i = 0; i < m_jArry.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jo_inside = m_jArry.getJSONObject(i);

    String Original = jo_inside.getString("from");
    String To = jo_inside.getString("to");

    if(isMethodConvertingIn){
        EnteredString = EnteredString.replace(" ","_");
        EnteredString = EnteredString.replace(Original,To + " ");
    } else {
        EnteredString = EnteredString.replace("_"," ");
        EnteredString = EnteredString.replace(To + " ", Original);
    }
}

LoadingProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
SetResultText(EnteredString);
ShowResultCardView();
```

For example, the json response is :

```
{
    "Response":[
        {"from":"a","to":"bhduh"},{"from":"b","to":"eieja"},{"from":"tes","to":"neesj"}
    ]
}
```

`String.replace()` method won't work here, because first it will replace `a` to `bhduh`, then `b` to `eieja`, BUT here's the problem, it will convert `b` in `bhduh` to `eieja`, which i don't want to.

I want to perfectly convert the letters and "words" in the String according the Json, but that what i'm failing at .

New Code :

```
if(m_jArry.length() > 0){
    HashMap<String, String> m_li;

    EnteredString = EnteredText.getText().toString();

    Log.i("TestAf_","Before Converting: "  + EnteredString);

    HashMap<String,String> replacements = new HashMap<String,String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < m_jArry.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jo_inside = m_jArry.getJSONObject(i);

        String Original = jo_inside.getString("from");
        String To = jo_inside.getString("to");

        if(isMethodConvertingIn){

            //EnteredString = EnteredString.replace(" ","_");

            replacements.put(Original,To);
            Log.i("TestAf_","From: " + Original + " - To: " + To + " - Loop: " + i);
            //EnteredString = EnteredString.replace(" ","_");
            //EnteredString = EnteredString.replace(Original,To + " ");

        } else {

            EnteredString = EnteredString.replace("_"," ");
            EnteredString = EnteredString.replace("'" + To + "'", Original);
        }

    }
    Log.i("TestAf_","After Converting: " + replaceTokens(EnteredString,replacements));

    // Replace Logic Here
    // When Finish, Do :
    LoadingProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    SetResultText(replaceTokens(EnteredString,replacements));
    ShowResultCardView();
```

Output :

```
10-10 19:51:19.757 12113-12113/? I/TestAf_: Before Converting: ab a ba
10-10 19:51:19.757 12113-12113/? I/TestAf_: From: a - To: bhduh - Loop: 0
10-10 19:51:19.757 12113-12113/? I/TestAf_: From: b - To: eieja - Loop: 1
10-10 19:51:19.757 12113-12113/? I/TestAf_: From: o - To: neesj - Loop: 2
10-10 19:51:19.758 12113-12113/? I/TestAf_: After Converting: ab a ba
```

Comment: do the conversions follow a specific pattern? or is it all arbitrary?

Comment: One solution would be to use some kind of markup for the replacement `{replacement}` for example, and replace step by step taking into account `{` and `}`, at the end, strip the delimiting `{}`

Comment: I think what @RC. is saying, is something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959731/how-to-replace-a-set-of-tokens-in-a-java-string

Comment: I've posted a question about regex in my profile, i was thinking about adding `'` `'`  befoe and after the changed letter, and when conveting the string, i will check if it's inside `'` or not, if YES then don't convert it, if NO then convert it, but this idea didn't work, because it was really complex to make, it worked on low count letters, but when writing whole words, it failed .

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks I was looking for an example ;) The idea is to insert delimiter to avoid replacement of replacement

Comment: @k3v1n No, it's based on the response, and not like what @ cricket_007 showed as an example.

Comment: It kinda is... You replace `a` with `[a]`, (brackets could be any characters) then you can follow along with that post, I think

Comment: Do I understand that you only want to change whole words? Would 'ab' get changed to 'bhduheieja' or would it stay 'ab'?

Comment: ab would change to eiejahduheieja, because there's a `b` in the first .

Comment: You just contradicted the question text... you complained that "it will replace `a` to `bhduh` ... but here's the problem, it will convert `b` in `bhduh` to `eieja`, which I don't want to." I'm confused now.

Comment: Hmm, you misunderstood, i want to change the letters/String in the EnteredString, what's happening is, it's replacing the letters/String in the EnteredString and Converted one, so `bhduh` is converted, i don't want to replace the converted one.

Comment: I'm asking what you *want* `ab` to turn into.

Comment: it should be `bhduheieja`

Comment: I've updated the code, I've used the provided code in @cricket_007 comment, after checking it didn't convert any letters/strings, I'm gonna update it with output to see where's the problem .

Comment: @AboHani I think I have a solution for you, but I would chat with you before to be sure it is the right solution.

Comment: Yeah sure, no problem.

Comment: It depends on how the `replaceTokens()` method has been implemented. Is it possible for you to post that code as well?

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has mentioned this. If you're looking for speed, construct a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (prefix tree) from your result since your `from` values potentially have more than one character. This is _literally_ what they're for.

Comment: @Qix can you post an example ?

Comment: @Shiraz. M the method is in the answers, you can check it up, or check the link which was posted by cricket_007

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an method which is strictly just Java. I tried not to use any Java 8 methods here.

```
public static String translate(final String str, List<String> from, List<String> to, int index) {
    StringBuilder components = new StringBuilder();
    String token, replace;
    int p;

    if (index < from.size()) {
        token = from.get(index);
        replace = to.get(index);
        p = 0;

        for (int i = str.indexOf(token, p); i != -1; i = str.indexOf(token, p)) {
            if (i != p) {
                components.append(translate(str.substring(p, i), from, to, index + 1));
            }
            components.append(replace);
            p = i + token.length();
        }
        return components.append(translate(str.substring(p), from, to, index + 1)).toString();
    }

    return str;
}

public static String translate(final String str, List<String> from, List<String> to) {
    if (null == str) {
        return null;
    }
    return translate(str, from, to, 0);
}
```

### Sample test program

```
public static void main(String []args) {
    String EnteredString = "aa  hjkyu  batesh  a";
    List<String> from = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "tes"));
    List<String> to = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("bhduh", "eieja", "neesj"));

    System.out.println(translate(EnteredString, from, to));
}
```

### Output:

```
bhduhbhduh  hjkyu  eiejabhduhneesjh  bhduh
```

---

### Explaination

The algorithm is recursive, and it simply does the following

- If a pattern found in the string matches a pattern in the `from` list

  - if there is any string before that pattern, apply the algorithm to that string
  - replace the found pattern with the corresponding pattern in the `to` list
  - append the replacement to the new string
  - discard the pattern in the `from` list and repeat the algorithm for the rest of the string
- Otherwise append the rest of the string to the new string

Answer (score 4):

You question would be clearer if you gave the expected output for the function.

Assuming it is: `ab b test a b >>>> bhduheieja eieja neesjt bhduh eieja`

then see the following, the key point in the Javadoc being "This will not repeat"

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replaceEach(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[])

> Replaces all occurrences of Strings within another String.
>   A null reference passed to this method is a no-op, or if any "search
>   string" or "string to replace" is null, that replace will be ignored.
>   ***This will not repeat.*** For repeating replaces, call the overloaded
>   method.

**Example 1**

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class StringReplacer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "ab b test a b";
        String output = StringUtils.replaceEach(input, new String[] { "a", "b", "tes" },
                new String[] { "bhduh", "eieja", "neesj" });

        System.out.println(input + " >>>> " + output);
    }
}
```

**Example 2**

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class StringReplacer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "this is a test string with foo";
        String output = StringUtils.replaceEach(input, new String[] { "a", "foo" },
                new String[] { "foo", "bar"});

        System.out.println(input + " >>>> " + output);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try following:

**Solution 1:**
Traverse the `String` characters one by one and move the new `String` to a new `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`, then call `toString()` to get the result. This will need you to implement string matching algorithm.

**Solution 2 (Using Regex):**
For this, you must know the domain of your string. For example, it is `[a-zA-Z]` then other arbitrary characters (not part of domain) can be used for intermediate step. ***First replace the actual characters with arbitrary one then arbitrary ones with the target***. In example below, `[!@#]` are the arbitrary characters. These can be any random `\uxxxx` value as well.

```
String input = "a-b-c";
String output = input.replaceAll("[a]", "!").replaceAll("[b]", "@").replaceAll("[c]", "#");
output = output.replaceAll("[!]", "bcd").replaceAll("[@]", "cde").replaceAll("[#]", "def");
System.out.println("input: " + input);
System.out.println("Expected: bcd-cde-def");
System.out.println("Actual: " + output);
```

Comment: Your solution 1 is the most robust. I hate seeing everyone jump to RegEx due to laziness. This is _not_ a good case for RegEx and _not_ a good (enough) reason to bring in Apache Commons if you're not already working with it. This is a perfect use-case for a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is quite common. To sum things up :

```
String test = "this is a test string with foo";
System.out.println(test.replace("a", "foo").replace("foo", "bar"));
```

Gives : `this is bar test string with bar`

Expected by you : `this is foo test string with bar`

You can use [StrSubstitutor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html) from **Apache Commons Lang**

But first you will have to inject placeholders in your string :

```
String test = "this is a test string with foo";

Map<String, String> valuesMap = new HashMap<>();
valuesMap.put("a", "foo");
valuesMap.put("foo", "bar");
String testWithPlaceholder = test;
// Preparing the placeholders
for (String value : valuesMap.keySet())
{
    testWithPlaceholder = testWithPlaceholder.replace(value, "${"+value+"}");
}
```

And then, use `StrSubstitutor`

```
System.out.println(StrSubstitutor.replace(testWithPlaceholder, valuesMap));
```

It gives : `this is foo test string with bar`

Answer (score 1):

You could use split like: 
`String[] pieces = jsonResponse.split("},{");` 
then you just parse the from and to in each piece and apply them with replace() then put the string back together again. (and please get your capitalization of your variables/methods right - makes it very hard to read the way you have it)

Answer (score 1):

Apache Commons [`StringUtils::replaceEach`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replaceEach-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-) does this.

```
String[] froms = new String[] {"a", "b"};
String[] tos = new String[] {"b","c"};
String result = StringUtils.replaceEach("ab", froms, tos);
// result is "bc"
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not keep it very simple (if the JSON is always in same format, EG: from the same system). Instead of replacing `from` with `to`, replace the entire markup:

replace `"from":"*from*"` with `"from":"*to*"`

Answer (score -3):

Why not just change the actual "to" and "from" labels?  That way, you don't run into a situation where "bhudh" becomes "eieja".  Just do a string replace on "from" and "to".

Comment: Example ? because i didn't really get what you mean.